# Would adding this feature to Java make sense: default member collections?

Tags: java

I what to iterate over a collection that is a member of a class. The syntax current is

```
for (Foo f: bar.getFoos()){...
```

I am simply proposing

```
 for (Foo f: bar){...
```

It would be understood if there was only one collection of Foo in the Bar class that the getter would be invoked or if no getter the collection would be directly accessed (if public).

Comment: ...and then someone else comes along six months later and adds a second collection to that class and all of a sudden a bunch of stuff stops compiling.

Comment: If it makes sense for `Bar` to implement `Iterable<Foo>`, that's fine. If it's got `Foos` and `Bazs` and `Frobnitzes`, no.

Comment: `Bar` can implement the `Iterable` interface, and have the `iterator`-method return the iterator of your collection.

Comment: _"t would be understood if there was only one collection of Foo in the Bar class"_ and the code will break as soon as there is another collection accessor needed in foo...

Comment: Apart from the problems that might occur, what exactly is the advantage? Not having to write .getFoos()? Laziness is a virtue of programming, sure, but... That said, I like the question, makes one think about basic syntax, even if one is against the proposed feature.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not that good of an idea because as JonK suggests, you could add a second collection of the same type to the class and every piece of code referring to the collection is this way either would stop compiling or would refer to the wrong collection (if, say, it referred to the first occurrence).

EDIT: I have to revise this. If a second collection were added the code would refer to the first collection still. I think this could in fact be a feature, just as functional interfaces, which rely on a single method, are employed.

Comment: Indeed: the best way to make it "understood if there was only one collection of Foo in the Bar class..." is to make users of the class access that one collection explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see hot this would create the need for a feature. If you want to iterate over a `Bar` gettin `Foo`s, just let `Bar` implement `Iterable<Foo>` and return an appropriate `Iterator<Foo>`. Don't forget to provide appropriate `.stream()` and `.parallelStream()` functions as they may become handy as well.